# Does the Kotlin Fold Function require type casting or specifying lambda type?

Tags: kotlin, types, casting, fold

I am looking at the documentation for the Kotlin fold function and am having a bit of difficulty understanding what is going on. The example they provide is as follows:

```
val fruits = listOf("apple", "apricot", "banana", "blueberry", "cherry", "coconut")

// collect only even length Strings
val evenFruits = fruits.groupingBy { it.first() }
    .fold(listOf<String>()) { acc, e -> if (e.length % 2 == 0) acc + e else acc }

println(evenFruits) // {a=[], b=[banana], c=[cherry]}
```

They say there should only be a single "operation function" as an argument.

`.fold(listOf<String>()) { acc, e -> if (e.length % 2 == 0) acc + e else acc }`

However, in addition to the lambda, they also have the `(listOf<String>())` part. While the lack of parentheses around arguments on some function calls confuses me sometimes, I imagine this can't possibly be a function call all on its own. Does the Kotlin fold Function require typecasting or specifying lambda type? If I get rid of that code snippet it breaks. I was pretty sure that the only way to specify a type was anonymous functions with a return type and not lambdas so I'm really not too sure what is going on here. I am new to Kotlin so any explanations as to what this syntax means and how the fold function works would be appreciated.

Here is the link to the documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the linked documentation you can see there are 2 arguments:

```
inline fun <T, R> Iterable<T>.fold(
    initial: R,
    operation: (acc: R, T) -> R
): R
```

By the [trailing lambda](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#passing-a-lambda-to-the-last-parameter) rule, the call is another way to write

```
.fold(listOf<String>(), { acc, e -> if (e.length % 2 == 0) acc + e else acc })
```

So `initial` is `listOf<String>()` and `operation` is `{ acc, e -> if (e.length % 2 == 0) acc + e else acc }`. The reason `String` needs to be specified in `listOf<String>()` is that it helps the compiler figure out that `R` is `List<String>` and then it knows the types of both arguments in `{ acc, e -> ... }`.

> If I get rid of that code snippet it breaks.

If you mean just removing `(listOf<String>())` then you are left with one argument, and `fold` requires two.

> Does the Kotlin fold Function require typecasting or specifying lambda type?

Well, there is no typecasting or specifying lambda type in the example, so it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you, the trailing lambda was my missing piece! I just want to clarify one thing, they have two sections that are titled "parameters". The first section has two params as you mentioned: initial and operation. The second section at the very bottom has only the operation parameter listed. Is this actually an overload or is there some default thing that they assume in that case? Or is something else going on there?

Comment: @SamiWood Both "Parameters" sections apply only to the overload they are listed under (the two `Grouping<T, K>.fold` overloads). I don't know why the last one lists only one parameter when it has two, but even that is incomplete ("operation - a function that is invoked on each element with the following parameters:" and the parameters aren't actually given). The overload which you use is in the first block which doesn't have a "Parameters" section. I don't know why but the meaning of parameters is given in the main text.